# How to print boolean in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I already know how to use log with different format and i already read this wiki

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_CCLOG

I want to print bool in my game. (The output is intended for me, not for the end user.)

```
bool x=true;
```

How i check what is the status of x in runtime ??

Comment: You could print it as a simple unsigned integer (either 0 or 1) with `CCLOG("Value: %u", (unsigned)x);`.

Comment: I like using tenery operator e.g. `CCLOG("x:%s",(x?"true":"false"));`

Comment: You want to print a `bool` in your game? Are you assuming that the player  is a programmer and knows what a `bool` is? Print something that's meaningful *to the user* in context.

Comment: @KeithThompson dear bool is for me, not for user. I have a class having one data member of type bool and i want to print the value of that variable. That's all. I know what is the difference between model and view.

Comment: Then please add that information to the question.

Comment: I've added the information to your question.

Comment: I see you've unaccepted my answer. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually I want to delete this question because too many downvote so when tried to delete it. I got a prompt that accepted answer can't be deleted so I unaccept it, further I m not able to delete so I flagged in moderatror intervention for deletation,.

Comment: @KeithThompson moderator declined my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the output is intended for you, not for the end user, you can print it in any format you like.

`CCLOG` appears to be based on `printf`. Like `printf`, it has no special format specifier for `bool`.

The simplest approach is to convert the value to an integer type, yielding `0` or `1`:

```
CCLOG("x = %d\n", (int)x);
```

(Yes, you should cast the value; since `int` and `bool` are likely to have different sizes, they might not be passed as variadic arguments in the same way.)

If you want the output to be a bit more user-friendly:

```
CCLOG("x = %s\n", x ? "true" : "false");
```